# NFS Unknown reason for rejecting rpc message

Tags: linux, rpc, nfs, tcpdump, suse

I see frequent rpc rejection messages from NFS server and slow NFS I/O. What could be a cause for RPC rejection and can it cause nfs failure ?

```
nfsserver.nfs > nfsclient.itm-mcell-s: Flags [.], cksum 0xa3c6 (correct), seq 914857:916305, ack 710776, win 65535, options [nop,nop,TS val 108960006 ecr 12472094], length 1448: NFS reply xid 46996 reply ERR 0: Unknown reason for rejecting rpc message 420
```

- Sachin

Answer (score -1):

Appears to be issue in nfs readdirplus calls. Packeted analyzed in tcpdump all are readdirplus calls.

Suse 12 sp1 nfs client readdirplus is slow/rejected by server. After i mounted noreaddirplus options rpc rejection message are stopped.

- Sachin